# How to create color randomizer in python

Tags: python, python-turtle

So I'm still new to using lists and I just want to make the background color change when the player reaches a certain score. All i've been able to piece together is that i need to put it in the mainloop but i don't know how to make a list and much less how to randomize it

Comment: Please provide clarity to this question. Are you looking specifically for help on the randomization, the colors, or the UI elements?

Comment: Hello, if you want to have a higher chance of people helping you, please take a look at the how to ask a good question [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

With the built-in random module you can take a random value from a list.

```
import random
colours = ['red', 'green', 'blue'] # define the list
random_colour = random.choice(colours) #take 1 random choice out of the 'colours' list
```

`random_colour` now contains a random string from the `colours` list